# ClickOnce : deploy files to different location

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

Using ClickOnce, is it possible to include a file (resource, dll, image, whatever) to be copied to a **different** location and NOT the app folder?

What I am trying to achieve exactly is to install **Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll** + **Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll** and their **.targets** to *C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web* so those msbuild tasks can be used on workstations that do not have Visual Studio installed.

It was so easy using a Setup Project before VS 2013!!

I repeat: I do NOT want those files to be installed in the app folder (so please don't tell me to set the option Copy to Output = Always" on project files).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't do it with ClickOnce.

Either deploy the files and write code to copy files when your app starts. Or use some other deployment option, like msi.